# Typescript return types with .getElementsByClassName()

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom, selector

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around the discrepancy in results when I call `getElementsByClassName` on two different elements:

Consider the following code:

```
let section:HTMLElement = document.getElementById("mainSection");

// This returns NodeListOf<Element>
let blah1 = section.getElementsByClassName("blah");

// This returns HTMLCollectionOf<Element>
let blah2 = document.getElementsByClassName("blah");
```

Why is it that when I call the method on on `section` I get a `NodeList` but when I call it on document, I get an `HTMLCollection`?

Based on the [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName), shouldn't they both return an `HTMLCollection`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The javascript `document` object only contains valid HTML elements, that's a guarantee by standards.

However, HTML elements (which your `selection` is) can contain other HTML elements or nodes that aren't valid html (think plain text, which is a node, but can not (legally) exist by itself in the Javascript document).

NodeList and HTMLCollection are nearly identical, but using traditional object oriented language, HTMLCollection extends NodeList, that is, it can do everything NodeList can, but it also has the `namedItem` method.

Comment: I understand that `HTMLElements` can contain non-valid HTML nodes. However, if I'm using `getElementsByClassName()`, wouldn't I only be getting valid HTML elements that match the class? I couldn't be getting plain text in return if I'm explicitly calling a method that searches for Elements by their class name.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` when run on an arbitrary element could also return SVG elements, which are not HTML elements